# An unpredictable function

Tags: javascript

In the book [Node design patterns](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/nodejs-design-patterns/9781839214110/) found this (but it was not clear the reason for the problem presented below):

> One of the most dangerous situations is to have an API that behaves
> synchronously under certain conditions and asynchronously under
> others. Let's take the following code as an example:
>
> ```
> import { readFile } from 'fs'
> const cache = new Map()
> function inconsistentRead (filename, cb) {
>   if (cache.has(filename)) {
>     // invoked synchronously
>     cb(cache.get(filename))
>   } else {
>     // asynchronous function
>     readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
>       cache.set(filename, data)
>       cb(data)
>     })
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The preceding function uses the cache map to store the results of
> different file read operations. Now, let's see how the use of an
> unpredictable function, such as the one that we just defined, can
> easily break an application. Consider the following code:
>
> ```
> function createFileReader (filename) {
>   const listeners = []
>   inconsistentRead(filename, value => {
>     listeners.forEach(listener => listener(value))
>   })
>   return {
>     onDataReady: listener => listeners.push(listener)
>   }
> }
>
>
>
> const reader1 = createFileReader('data.txt')
> reader1.onDataReady(data => {
>   console.log(`First call data: ${data}`)
>   // ...sometime later we try to read again from
>   // the same file
>   const reader2 = createFileReader('data.txt')
>   reader2.onDataReady(data => {
>     console.log(`Second call data: ${data}`)
>   })
> })
> ```

The result (print):

```
First call data: some data
```

Why is only the first `console.log` being called?

Comment: I get the sense that it is your use of the function that is causing inconsistency here, not the function itself; nested listeners and side effects too late in the flow.

Comment: Just a heads up,  if you use modern JS features like `async / await`,  problems like this are less likely.  Callbacks can get very confusing, and Promises & async / await really simplify this.  Creating a fileCache with `async / await` would work in the way you would expect.  Node these days also has the `fs/promises` module that make it very simple.

Comment: @Keith I do however see ""The callback-based versions of the fs module APIs are preferable over the use of the promise APIs when maximal performance (both in terms of execution time and memory allocation are required)." "

Comment: @mplungjan  Yes, promises have a slight overhead, but with the added bonus of implicit error handling, that the OP has totally missed out in the question, Promises even in performance area's I would say is preferable.  On my 8 year old PC I'm using at work, and `async / await` on noOp fn does about 2743389 Ops/sec,  yes, callbacks will do substantially more but any performance gains at this level would be very very small.  Going back maybe a few years ago when Promises were not native I can see it been more an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author actually answers the question

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781783287314/1/ch01lvl1sec10/the-callback-pattern

> Then, reader2 is created in a cycle of the event loop in which the cache for the requested file already exists. In this case, the inner call to inconsistentRead() will be synchronous. So, its **callback will be invoked immediately**, which means that also all the listeners of reader2 will be invoked synchronously. **However, we are registering the listeners after the creation of reader2, so they will never be invoked.**

So what that means: When the file is already in cache the client does not get a chance to assign the event handler until the event has already passed.

```
const reader2 = createFileReader('data.txt'); // this is so fast
reader2.onDataReady(data => {  // that this is not assigned until after onDataReady
  console.log(`Second call data: ${data}`)
})
```

**Solution**: Move the actual read to AFTER you assign the event handler

Alternatively have a read about [process.nextTick](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-processnexttick/)

which seems to be able to help this issue if you do not want to do what I suggest above

```
const consistentRead = (filename, cb) => {
  if (cache.has(filename)) {
    // Ensuring asynchronous invocation
    process.nextTick(() => cb(cache.get(filename)));
  } else {
    readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      cache.set(filename, data);
      cb(data);
    });
  }
}
```

---

To simplify the explanation, compare it to this simpler example where adding the event listener after the thing that will trigger it, may fail if the event is very short

```
let img = new Image(); 
img.src = "somesmallfile"; // if this is really small or in cache
img.addEventListener("load",() => console.log('loaded')); // this event listener is assigned AFTER the load is triggered
```

to the much safer

```
let img = new Image();  
img.addEventListener("load",() => console.log('loaded')); 
img.src = "somesmallfile"; // NOW the above event listener will trigger
```

Comment: I never did, but I must admit I'm confused with what has `let img = new Image();` in relation to the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah, I can see were you coming from, your using `Image` client side as an example, but the OP would need to alter his API here to work in the same way.  Currently he's just using a function that passes the filename, and not an object with a property filename that could be used to trigger the event.  I think your `process.nextTick(` is the simple answer.  Anyway, I'll do a counter-vote, as I agree the down-votes are not warranted, why people can't just comment first, I've no idea.. :)

Comment: Ok, so the author actually answered it, but perhaps my explanation makes it more clear.